# Silverlight 3: No change but now I am getting "Page Not Found"

Tags: silverlight, navigation

Had a page that was working fine. Only change I made was to add a datagrid to the page (which also added the xmlns) and all of the sudden I'm getting Page Not Found. Checked the UriMappings. Tried the default nav link. No joy.

Ideas?

UPDATE: The answer was that I had a mock class that was not initializing a collection. See Byrant's answer for a way to save yourself some time.

Comment: Does it start working if you remove the datagrid?  Where do you get the error, is it a 404 in the browser or a Silverlight error?  More details please.

Comment: Is your Page Not Found a Silverlight error or are you getting a true 404 page not found in your browser?  I've seen the Silverlight error when a static resource isn't setup correctly and throws an error.  It's odd that it shows a Page Not Found error instead of something else but that's how it goes.  Also, are you binding the datagrid's itemsource to anything yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To see what the issue is you need to make one change to your MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
// If an error occurs during navigation, show an error window
private void ContentFrame_NavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
{
    Exception ex = e.Exception;

    while (ex.InnerException != null)
    {
        ex = ex.InnerException;
    }

    e.Handled = true;
    ChildWindow errorWin = new ErrorWindow(ex);
    errorWin.Show();
}
```

Once you've made that change when you start the application you should see the exception instead of the page where the exception occurred.

Comment: I'd nailed it down to a mock class not initializing a collection by the time I saw your answer. I made your changes and they would have saved me about an hour. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Firebug is always a good friend to see which kind of requests are called ...
Often the devServer is not closed properly , have a look at the taskbar

Comment: That's what I thought had happened and was one of the first things I'd checked. Thanks for the idea!!! See other answer for cause.