# Silverlight cant find page error

Tags: silverlight, navigation

I have started a a new project (to refactor some code), and just can't work out why I keep getting "Can't find page /Index" error.  The code works fine until I use an **add** method (on any collection type). So I don't think there is a problem with the navigation, but an issue with my IndexViewModel class.

public partial class Index : Page
    {
        private IndexViewModel _vm;

```
    public Index()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _vm = new IndexViewModel();
```

...

```
public class IndexViewModel //: ViewModelBase
    {                                         
        public SortableCollectionView Rows {get;set;}          

        public IndexViewModel()
        {
            // generate some dummy data
            Random rand = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
            {
                Row row = new Row();
                row["stuff"] = s_names[rand.Next(s_names.Length)];

                **Rows.Add(row);**

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you never new up your Rows variable.

```
Rows = new SortableCollectionView();
```

To get to the actual error you can use this trick copied from my answer on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650393/silverlight-3-no-change-but-now-i-am-getting-page-not-found/1650639#1650639):

To see what the issue is you need to make one change to your MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
// If an error occurs during navigation, show an error window
private void ContentFrame_NavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
{
    Exception ex = e.Exception;

    while (ex.InnerException != null)
    {
        ex = ex.InnerException;
    }

    e.Handled = true;
    ChildWindow errorWin = new ErrorWindow(ex);
    errorWin.Show();
}
```

Once you've made that change when you start the application you should see the exception instead of the page where the exception occurred.

Comment: lol, man what a noob! 
Yea problem solved, I have spent all morning staring at my code.  Need more sleep obviously.

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
Rows = new SortableCollectionView();
```

somewhere in your code.